# Can't connect to database using ExternalName on GKE in an ExpressJS Application

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kube-dns

I want to connect multiple microservices hosted on Google Kubernetes Engine to a MongoDB Atlas database.

All Deployments and Services inside the cluster are on the `gitlab-managed-apps` namespace.

I have created the following ExternalName Service:

**mongo-external-name.yaml**

```sh
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: db_name.mrud5.mongodb.net
```

To connect to MongoDB Atlas I tried to use the ExternalName since using *db_name.mrud5.mongodb.net* would try to resolve to an internal service:

```js
//connect.js
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${ global.DB_USER }:${ global.DB_PASSWORD }@mongo.gitlab-managed-apps.svc.cluster.local/${ global.DB_NAME }?retryWrites=true&w=majority`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
    });
```

As per the deployments, I have them inside a couple of Helm Charts. I thought it had something to do with the `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst` and I attempted to set it to `dnsPolicy: Default`, but that made no difference.

Upon executing bash on one of the pods, I have tried `nslookup` as suggested by many other issues, this is the result:

```sh
bash-5.0# nslookup mongo.gitlab-managed-apps.svc.cluster.local
Server:         10.1.0.10
Address:        10.1.0.10:53

    mongo.gitlab-managed-apps.svc.cluster.local     canonical name = db_name.mrud5.mongodb.net

    mongo.gitlab-managed-apps.svc.cluster.local     canonical name = db_name.mrud5.mongodb.net
```

I figured that if the pod can see the CNAME records there must be something else that I am not doing right.

I was unable to `ping mongo.gitlab-managed-apps.svc.cluster.local`

```sh
bash-5.0# ping mongo.gitlab-managed-apps.svc.cluster.local
ping: bad address 'mongo.gitlab-managed-apps.svc.cluster.local'
```

My cluster's master version is `1.15.11-gke.15`. I did not create the cluster with this version, upon creation, Gitlab automatically chose `1.14.10`. After reading multiple issues on GitHub, I understood that there were some issues with `kube-dns` on version `1.14.9`. I, therefore, ran the command below to try to fix this.

```sh
kubectl set image deployment/kube-dns -n kube-system \
  kubedns=gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.10 \
  dnsmasq=gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64:1.14.10 \
  sidecar=gcr.io/google_containers/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64:1.14.10
```

As I thought, this was not the solution either. Desperate, I upgraded the cluster to `1.15.11-gke.15` and kube-dns with the above command. That was not the solution either.

I don't think it causes this problem but I have posted below my Ingress controller:

**ingress-service.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100m"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "7200"
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - my.host
      secretName: letsencrypt-prod
  rules:
    - host: my.host
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: my-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
            path: /?(.*)
```

Any suggestion is very much appreciated!

Comment: is your cluster vpc native?

Comment: @SebaArriagada I'm not sure since the cluster was created via Gitlab so it might have used the REST API, but I can tell you that *VPC-native (alias IP) is Enabled*, so I assume it must be VPC Native.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `ExternalName` configuration is correct ✅. Your cluster pods are giving you the right canonical name. However, `db_name.mrud5.mongodb.net` is not even pingable nor reachable. It's basically a TXT DNS record. I say this because I tried it myself with my DB:

```sh
dig txt mycluster.vvcme.mongodb.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> txt cluster0.vvcme.mongodb.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18012
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cluster0.vvcme.mongodb.net.    IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mycluster.vvcme.mongodb.net. 60 IN  TXT "authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-xxxxxx-shard-0"

;; Query time: 127 msec
;; SERVER: 10.240.246.53#53(10.240.246.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Jul 17 19:26:52 PDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105
```

This is used by the client to get all the shards but in essence, you can find the shards directly:

```sh
dig srv _mongodb._tcp.mycluster.vvcme.mongodb.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> srv _mongodb._tcp.mycluster.vvcme.mongodb.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5089
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_mongodb._tcp.mycluster.vvcme.mongodb.net. IN SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vvcme.mongodb.net. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 mycluster-shard-00-00.vvcme.mongodb.net. 
_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vvcme.mongodb.net. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 mycluster-shard-00-01.vvcme.mongodb.net. 
_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.vvcme.mongodb.net. 60 IN SRV 0 0 27017 mycluster-shard-00-02.vvcme.mongodb.net. 

...
```

Those shards are actually pingable and DNS resolvable:

```sh
dig cluster0-shard-00-00.vvcme.mongodb.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> cluster0-shard-00-00.vvcme.mongodb.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 41225
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cluster0-shard-00-00.vvcme.mongodb.net.    IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mycluster-shard-00-00.vvcme.mongodb.net.    60 IN CNAME mtm-aws-use1-22-m0-14-shard-00-00.5yapb.mongodb.net.
mtm-aws-use1-22-m0-14-shard-00-00.5yapb.mongodb.net. 60 IN CNAME ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. 86400 IN A xx.xxx.xx.xx 

...
```

All this stuff is available on the open internet and it's [documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/). So you don't even need your `ExternalName` Kubernetes service. Unless for some reason you are running Atlas in your private VPC in which case you would have to configure/ping the appropriate records. ✌️

Comment: I see. The reason I attempted to use ExternalNames is because I keep receiving the error `MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster.` if I use a connection string like `mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@mycluster.vvcme.mongodb.net/<db_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. That only happens inside a Pod, on my development machine where I don't use Kubernetes the connection is successful. Can you please share a connection string that you would use in this case? Edit: 0.0.0.0/0 is Whitelisted in Atlas.

Comment: I would like to point out that I have managed to solve the issue but not the way I wanted to. I was hosting the database on Atlas using AWS. I created another cluster on GCP and it worked like a charm. Could this mean that I needed to add some special permissions in order to connect from GKE to an Atlas hosted AWS MongoDB Cluster? I don't see how I would be able to do that since Atlas does not provide acces to AWS directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to get the database to work using an Atlas Cluster hosted using AWS, but **I was able to connect to an Atlas Cluster hosted using GCP.**

So as a temporary fix if anybody comes by this issue, just create an Atlas Cluster using GCP.

I will leave the question open as the issue was avoided, not solved.